# Encryption & Decryption in C++ Using IO File

Tags: c++, file, encryption, io

I have a program that take a text file and encrypts it this program works fine but to decrypt the ciphered file again there is a problem in reading it's contents and really i do not know why?

the output file contains:

```
u،~«چںaJj²طوڑظپهزz^®h6´؛تٌSaطyْ²ٍbزyàê–è@؛
wF¹LVچ‍ï§ک²ٍهئ‹غ·z)²7œf&€¬|{ ]O‘•RاMwvS,lج´رë€ت^M»بف_¢!d‏5و½CگّغS¨”dACc+Qoô
…إ·ؤâگض’‘إ2ك6@®eث2¼³َِ¢?]رْ³!§‰ Và¶¸é·¢‏7¢اV\»K18ض•5T¦k.و_ك~¯%ˆü}7ظ؟”b’~Q3Oهذ.™'!ذ7 ن‘ْژ‌,دحىZcFŒà{ْ\^¾عبzèںىھKَ9فPêفƒ®ظüکKپµŒ­اج¹ٌ:iده±=´yٌl.
2Aا#RطNc4   ‍ھ؟îِxDft£vâغ´©ے%5ح‹Oذâv€ا¯ْ4تùٌˆ–
¼
```

I am trying to read this file  but i cannot read all of the content.i can read only 117 char of it my code is:

```
 ifstream infilo;
 infilo.open("C:\\Dev-Cpp\\rc4\\in_cipher.txt");
 std::string cipher((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infilo)),
             std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

This code works good for the other programs.

Comment: make sure you open your file in binary mode

Comment: `infilo.open("C:\\Dev-Cpp\\rc4\\in_cipher.txt", ios::binary);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file in binary mode:

```
 infilo.open("C:\\Dev-Cpp\\rc4\\in_cipher.txt", std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
```

Comment: But if i read it in binary mode can i use the content of the string to do another processes,i am sorry for asking again but i am new in c++

Comment: It is encyrpted binary data, so it is technically not a string anymore. If you need to work on it as a string, you may consider converting the encrypted data to hex representation (or other format) or use an encryption method which outputs a string as it's encryption.

Comment: how can i use this file in binary in another process with char

Comment: a char is just an 8 byte value, so you can still process it as i.e a std::vector<char> instead of std::string.

Comment: Your welcome. Would be nice to accept the answer if it helped you.